# Rails app with state_machine gem getting "undefined method 'state_paths'..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, state-machine

In a Rails 3 app I have the following:

```
class Kase < ActiveRecord::Base
  state_machine :state, :initial => :lead do
    state :lead
    state :active
    state :completed

    event :reset_status do
      transition any => :lead
    end

    event :activate do
      transition any => :active
    end

    event :complete do
      transition any => :completed
    end
  end
end
```

The documentation (https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) shows that the following should be available for my situation:

```
vehicle.state_paths # => [[#<StateMachine::Transition ...], [#<StateMachine::Transition ...], ...]
vehicle.state_paths.to_states # => [:lead, :active, :completed]
```

However, when I run the following I get an error:

```
@kase = Kase.first
@kase.state
  => "lead"
@kase.state_paths
  NoMethodError: undefined method `state_paths' for #<Kase:0x00000100d95ca0> ...
```

I'm trying to get a list of all the possible states for a Kase. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

state_paths is not available in a released version of state_machine yet.  A new version will be released this week that includes the feature you're trying to use.

Comment: That's going to make my day! Thanks!

Comment: Hi again. Saw that this was updated to Tag 0.10.0. However, when I run, for example, @kase.status_paths my application just hangs. There are no errors thrown, but my ruby process goes to 100% and nothing happens. (PS. I'm now using :status instead of :state as the name of my state machine.) Any ideas? Thank you, and thanks for this great gem.

Comment: 0.10.1 seems to fix this. Thank you!